# Getting metadata from a video using Paperclip-FFMPEG in Rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, paperclip, metadata

While still a Rails newbie, I've managed to get [Paperclip-FFMPEG](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) working. However, I'd like to extract some metadata from the uploaded video, in particular the length of the video. The README suggests this is possible, but I'm struggling to understand what I need to do:

```
You may optionally add <attachment>_meta to your model and paperclip-ffmpeg will add information about the processed video.
```

Let's say the Paperclip attribute I have in my model is called "sourcefile". If I'm reading these instructions correctly, does this mean I need to add an extra attribute called sourcefile_meta? Do I need to add generate a migration file to add this extra column to the model's table? How would I get access to the length of the video in my view? Should it be something like this:

```
<p>Length: <%= mymodel.sourcefile_meta.length %></p>
```

Any pointers would be most useful, as I've hit a bit of a brick wall! Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Since the plugin is actively developed, might just want to file an issue and ask about how to actually implement this. "add to model" could mean the actual model or the database scheme, and it's unclear which info this would exactly provide.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to run a migration adding that field to your table as you mentioned, and ffmpeg-paperclip should autopopulate it, just as it does with the *_name field.